# Update Date Picker Value on LOST FOCUS

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a custom date picker in wpf below is the code of **xaml**

```
<local:Customdatepicker x:Uid="dateValue" 
    x:Name="dateValue" 
    BorderThickness="0" 
    Visibility="{Binding ShowDatePicker, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
    IsEnabled="{Binding FieldValueIsEditable, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"                                                DateCoordinates="{Binding CoOrdinates, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
    Text="{Binding DateFieldValue, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, TargetNullValue=''}"   
    Loaded="dateValue_Loaded" 
    Style="{StaticResource DatePickerStyle}" 
    Width="{Binding DatePickerWidth, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"                                                MouseDoubleClick="dateValue_MouseDoubleClick"  
    DisplayDate="{Binding DisplayDateFieldValue, Mode=TwoWay}"
    LostFocus="dateValue_LostFocus" />
```

**class**

```
public class Customdatepicker : DatePicker {
    public Customdatepicker() {
        DefaultStyleKey = typeof(DatePicker);
    }

    public _Coordinates DateCoordinates {
          get { return (_Coordinates) GetValue(CoordinatesProperty); }
          set { SetValue(CoordinatesProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CoordinatesProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("DateCoordinates", typeof(_Coordinates), typeof(Customdatepicker), null);
}
```

I want to validate date on **Lost focus** if I entered wrong date I want to update it but I'm unable to do so. Please let me know how I can do it on LOST FOCUS.

Comment: What will you validate? is it a correct format, or date entered shall be in a given range? I would override the `protected override void OnLostFocus(RoutedEventArgs e)` method in your `Customdatepicker` class and use `DependencyProperties` to define validation range or something like this. Maybe you can add your validation algorythm.

Comment: @WPFGermany instead of using this "LostFocus="dateValue_LostFocus""    i just tried this "Text="{Binding DateFieldValue, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus"  so instaed of property chnaged i have use Lost focus not...but can i use both at one time i.e property change and lost focus at one time..because i need the updated value also..

Answer (score 1):

I think there is some confusion about `Binding` and `UpdateSourceTrigger`.

First I would bind the `SelectedValue` like this instead using `x:Name`.

**View:**

```
<DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Path=SelDate, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

**ViewModel:**

```
private DateTime _selDate;
public DateTime SelDate {
    get { return _selDate; }
    set {
        if (value.Equals(_selDate)) return;
        /*
            here you could validate
        */
        _selDate = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(); //this updates view if changes done programmatically in your ViewModel (that implements INotifyPropertyChanged)
    }
}
```

with this simple `Binding` your **views** DatePicker has the same value as your **viewmodels** property.

Your validation now could be done in the `setter` (see comment) or you use the `OnLostFocus`. If you try validation in setter you have to mention that each change calls the setter.

The second possibility is to set the **views** binding like this:

```
<DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Path=SelDate, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

With this your setter in **viewmodel** is called when DatePicker lost its focus. Then you could validate in `setter` and it will been performed at `LostFocus`.

Hope that helped for understanding.

**Edit:**

For the current text you could add a several `Binding` on `Text`:

```
<DatePicker Text="{Binding DateText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

viewmodel:

```
...
public string DateText {
    get { return _dateText; }
    set {
        if (value == _dateText) return;
        _dateText = value;
        OnPropertyChange();
    }
}
```

**NOTE**: The texts value getting changed automatically on LostFocus an is Empty, if the string is `sadfs` .... But with that you can observe the text at the setter. I hope that helps.

Comment: thanks i got it but problem comes when i update any value in datepicker textbox like instead of "30.3.2016" i enter "sdfsdfds" but when i press lost focus i didn;t get the value i enter again i.e "sdfsdfds" the updated value any idea how can i get that  @WPFGermany

Comment: yes please look at my posted question i have used this in my xaml..but now problem comes that when i enter any  string in textbox it return null to property "DateText"  but when i enter any numeric value it returns me the date/value i.e is loaded intaillay..are you getting me.I need the updated value of any type

Comment: Thats the difference between `PropertyChanged` and `LostFocus`. At `LostFocus` the control performs checking internally and removes strings that are no valid time strings. If you bind with `PropertyChanged` you get each `change` / `typed char` (you can see this by adding a Breakpoint to the setter). When you lost the focus then, the setter is performed again with an empty value (thats the automatic from the control). If you like to do some magic between this you need to do the stuff in the setter.

Comment: Thanks a lot @WPFGermany for nice explanation ..but i was thinking magic will be done only when i have value with me in Lost focus...rest i try more